# Converting Raid5 to Raid1 - Cannot set new_offset

Tags: mdadm

I am trying to convert a 6 disk raid6 mdadm array to a 6 disk raid10 array. After hitting an `mdadm: Impossible level change requested`, I decided to try  with raid5, and so ran `mdadm --grow --level=5` and then `mdadm --grow /dev/md0 -n 5` successfilly. However, when I ran `mdadm --grow /dev/md0 --level raid10`, I hit the same error again. I decided to go from raid5 -> raid4 -> raid0 -> raid10, but for this too work, I need to have 3 disks at the raid0 stage, as I only have 6 disks.

However, after I managed to resize the array to be the suggested size for `mdadm --grow /dev/md0 -n 3`, I get the following error:

`mdadm: Cannot set new_offset for /dev/sda12`

When I remove `/dev/sda12` from the array, I get the same error, but for a different disk.

How do I fix/work around this error, or do I have to nuke the array and start a new one?

Comment: I think it's not posiible to live migrate from raid 6 to 10. from 5 to 0 it's possible but you need to decrase array size, and filesystem size. Creating new array will be quickly as converting.

Comment: @KrzysztofStasiak I have already live migrated from raid6 -> raid5, and I have decreased the array size. Since I'm using GPT on top of the array, resizing the actual data is a bit more tricky (and throws up many scary errors), but the error message saying the array was too large has been replaced with the error. The difficulty I'm having is in removing disks.

Comment: Do you decrease file system size before change array size? Is migration from 6 to 5 ended success?

Comment: @KrzysztofStasiak The migration went fine between raid6 and raid5, and I lost no data.

Comment: Ok, you have raid5 on 6 disk. I think you need to decrase filesystem size to 3 disk, and then migrate to raid0 with 3 drives. and then migrate to 10 specyfing 6 disk.

Comment: @KrzysztofStasiak That's what I am trying to do. Nice to see that it is not as mad as it seems :). However, the shrinking isn't working, as I think I specified in my question. If you need more details, just ask

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60270/discussion-between-krzysztof-stasiak-and-parallaxbeta).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converting from raid5 to raid10 need to convert raid5 -> raid0 and then raid0 -> raid 10.

You need to have array size smaller than target raid10 ( it will be smaller than raid 5).

To convert you need to specify disk count and target level:

`mdadm --grow /dev/md0 --level=0 --raid-devices=3 --backup-file=md0.backup`

(i suggest to do backup file)

you can monitor it by `cat /proc/mdstat`
  if by some time (20 mins) process gets stuck on `reshape =  0.0%` you need to use `--continue`:

`mdadm --grow /dev/md0 --level=0 --raid-devices=3 --backup-file=md0.backup --continue`

Comment: Sorry it took so long to mark as answer, I wanted to check it didn't kill everything first :)

Comment: I had a similar problem (same error: Cannot set new_offset) when shrinking a RAID5 array by one disk. I pondered a long time why it doesn't work when finally some digging in the mdadm source code brought me to the conclusion that it was because I didn't use the `--backup-file` argument. I didn't think it would make a difference, but apparently it does.

Comment: It is possible to make grow without backup-file, but not at all, i sugest to allways use backup-file. It could say that you need backup-file.